# How to add an array column to a table containing values from another column in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider table

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
)
```

After adding a `auth_identities varchar(128)[]` column I would not like to fill in the column with the values from `user_id` (as we want to support multiple different user identities in the future).

One way I managed to do this was

```sql
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD auth_identities VARCHAR(128)[];

UPDATE users u SET auth_identities=array((SELECT user_id FROM users u0 WHERE u0.user_id = u.user_id));
```

However, I don't particularly like how that `UPDATE` looks. Is there any way to make it a bit more idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a sub-select, just build an array from the existing column:

```
UPDATE users 
  SET auth_identities = array[user_id];
```